# Python sleep without interfering with script?

Tags: python, function, time, sleep

Hey I need to know how to sleep in Python without interfering with the current script. I've tried using `time.sleep()` but it makes the entire script sleep.

Like for example

```
import time
def func1():
    func2()
    print("Do stuff here")
def func2():
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Do more stuff here")
```

func1()

I want it to immediately print Do stuff here, then wait 10 seconds and print Do more stuff here.

Comment: you need to reorder your statements so they occur in the desired order

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Interpreting your description literally, you need to put the print statement before the call to `func2()`.

However, I'm guessing what you really want is for `func2()` to a background task that allows `func1()` to return immediately and not wait for `func2()` to complete it's execution. In order to do this, you need to create a thread to run `func2()`.

```
import time
import threading

def func1():
    t = threading.Thread(target=func2)
    t.start()
    print("Do stuff here")
def func2():
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Do more stuff here")

func1()
print("func1 has returned")
```

Comment: +1 Or another process. Or any other kind of concurrency (coroutines with a hand-written scheduler come to mind, although that's hardly practical).

Comment: @delnan: Yes. [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) would be another alternative to provide the same functionality in a different way. If we wanted another impractical solution, I'm sure there is something that involves pigeons that would work.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`threading.Timer`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading#timer-objects):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from threading import Timer

def func1():
    func2()
    print("Do stuff here")
def func2():
    Timer(10, print, ["Do more stuff here"]).start()

func1()
```

But as [@unholysampler already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136266/python-sleep-without-interfering-with-script/5136297#5136297) it might be better to just write:

```
import time

def func1():
    print("Do stuff here")
    func2()

def func2():
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Do more stuff here")

func1()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're running your script on command line, try using the `-u` parameter. It runs the script in unbuffered mode and did the trick for me.

For example:

`python -u my_script.py`