# sleep without interrupting program

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I am creating a program that counts down after a time, and asks for input of seconds to add to the countdown. (Not really, just an example). 
Kind of like this:

```
mytime = 10
while True:
   print(time)
   mytime -= 1
   time.sleep(1)
   mytime += int(input('add > '))
```

There is 2 problems.

1. I want the time to still tick down after a second, but don't want to have to wait the second before inputting. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136266/python-sleep-without-interfering-with-script). I think I need to use threading.
2. I don't want to wait for input either! I just want it to tick down without waiting for input, and when I want I can input things.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You will definitely need threading.

Comment: You called a variable time and used time module. 2 same names.

Comment: Whoops!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way than making your own thread from 0. Timer thread prepared for you:

```
import threading

timer = None

def wuf ():
    global timer
    print "Wuf-wuf!"
    timer = threading.Timer(5, wuf)
    timer.start()

timer = threading.Timer(5, wuf)
timer.start()
input() # Don't exit the program
```

This code will wait 5 seconds and then start printing "Wuf-wuf!" every 5 seconds.

If you want to stop it from main thread do:

```
timer.cancel()
```

But if you are writing a GUI application using event driven GUI system like wxPython or PyQT, then you should use theirs event managed timers. Especially if you are changing some GUI status from the timer callback.

Edit:
Oh, all right, here is your full answer:

```
import threading

seconds = 1 # Initial time must be the time+1 (now 0+1)
timer = None
def tick ():
    global seconds, timer
    seconds -= 1
    if seconds==0:
        print("%i seconds left" % seconds)
        print("Timer expired!")
        return
    # printing here will mess up your stdout in conjunction with input()
    print("%i second(s) left" % seconds)
    timer = threading.Timer(1, tick)
    timer.start()

seconds += int(input("Initial countdown interval: "))
tick()
while 1:
    seconds += int(input("Add: "))
    if not timer.is_alive():
        print("Restarting the timer!")
        seconds += 1
        tick()
```

Or easy version with thread (but a little clumsyer then using threading.Thread):

```
from thread import start_new_thread as thread
from time import sleep

seconds = 1 # Initial time+1
alive = 0
def _tick ():
    global seconds, alive
    try:
        alive = 1
        while 1:
            seconds -= 1
            if seconds==0:
                print("%i seconds left" % seconds)
                print("Timer expired!")
                alive = 0
                return
            # printing here will mess up your stdout in conjunction with input()
            print("%i second(s) left" % seconds)
            sleep(1)
    except: alive = 0

def tick ():
    thread(_tick,())

# Then same as above:
seconds += int(input("Initial countdown interval: "))
tick()
while 1:
    seconds += int(input("Add: "))
    if not alive:
        print("Restarting the timer!")
        seconds += 1
        tick()
```

You must realize that using the stdout within a thread will insert the printed text after the prompt message outputed by input().

This will be confusing. If you want to avoid this then you will have to write another thread that will get messages from a queue and output them.

If a last message was prompt message, then you will have to remove it from screen, write the new message, then return the prompt message, and position the cursor accordingly.

You could do it by implementing the file-like interface within the subclass of threading.Thread, then substituting sys.stdout with it. Perhaps overriding input() as well to indicate when a prompt message is out and stdin being read.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't fully answer my question.

Comment: How is the program being called everytime? I don't see a while True loop.

Comment: Program is not called, function wuf() is. Every time. Timer() initiates a a thread, it starts and waits, after interval expires it calls the given function and stops. Function wuf() sets a new Timer() that will call it again after interval expires. It is exactly what you want, you just have to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use threading to do so. All you have to do is create a subclass of [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) override the [`run()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.run) method and add some external control methods over the thread.

Here is a simple example you can try and tweak according to your own taste.

```
import threading
import time

class SleepingThread(threading.Thread):

  def __init__(self, sleep_for):
    super(SleepingThread, self).__init__()
    self.sleep_for = sleep_for

  def run(self):
    while self.sleep_for != 0:
      time.sleep(1)
      self.sleep_for -= 1
    print("Done sleeping")

  def add_seconds(self, seconds):
    self.sleep_for += seconds

  def get_sleep_for(self):
    return self.sleep_for

sleeping_thread = SleepingThread(10)
sleeping_thread.start()
while True:
  print(sleeping_thread.get_sleep_for())
  sleeping_thread.add_seconds(int(input('add > ')))
```

Don't forget to [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) if you want to go serious about it.

Comment: This is not completely what I want. It still waits for input, and I wanted it to print the new time everytime it decreased, not just after input.