# Interaction while time.sleep()?

Tags: python, arrays, time

let's say I want to make my program wait for 10 seconds with

```
time.sleep(10)
```

is there any chance to interact with the program while these 10 seconds of sleeping?

Comment: Well, no; it's sleeping. What does *interact* mean? Is this a console or GUI application?

Comment: What kind of interaction are you looking for? Maybe we can suggest different approach with a similar effect...

Comment: I mean interaction in general, for example a button push action or call a function while sleeping.

Comment: If you want the program to do something while it's sleeping, you'll have to use threads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sleep without interrupting program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420941/sleep-without-interrupting-program)

Comment: If you're in a GUI environment, you've almost certainly got some sort of scheduling ability available - Tkinter's `.after()` method for example.  You can use this to schedule something 10 seconds in the future, rather than sleeping for those 10 seconds - the program remains otherwise fully operational.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you mean, but here is a simple program that will allow user input while sleeping, then call a function at the end:

```
import threading, time

def foo():
    #function that accepts the input
    print('You typed:', input('Type something'))

def bar():
    #sleeping thread function
    time.sleep(10)
    print('Done!')

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=foo)  #thread for foo
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=bar)  #thread for bar
thread1.start()   #run foo thread
thread2.start()   #run bar thread
```

Please note that as python cannot output anything while waiting for `input()`, it will not print `Done!` until the input has been given, though the 10 second timer will be running.