# How to run tasks periodically without interrupting the whole program

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a program that constantly runs if it receives an input, it'll do a task then go right back to awaiting input. I'm attempting to add a feature that will ping a gaming server every 5 minutes, and if the results every change, it will notify me. Problem is, if I attempt to implement this, the program halts at this function and won't go on to the part where I can then input. I believe I need multithreading/multiprocessing, but I have no experience with that, and after almost 2 hours of researching and wrestling with it, I haven't been able to figure it out.

I have tried to use the recursive program I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420941/sleep-without-interrupting-program) but haven't been able to adapt it properly, but I feel this is where I was closest. I believe I can run this as two separate scripts, but then I have to pipe the data around and it would become messier. It would be best for the rest of the program to keep everything on one script.

```
'''python
def regular_ping(IP):
    last_status = None
    while True:
        present_status = ping_status(IP) #ping_status(IP) being another
                                         #program that will return info I 
                                         #need
        if present_status != last_status:
            notify_output(present_status) #notify_output(msg) being a 
                                          #program that will notify me of
                                          # a change
            last_status = present_status
        time.sleep(300)

'''
```

I would like this bit of code to run on its own, notifying me of a change (if there is one) every 5 minutes, while the rest of my program also runs and accepts inputs. Instead, the program stops at this function and won't run past it. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a thread or a process for this. But since this is not a CPU bound operation, overhead of dedicating a process is not worth it. So a thread would be enough. You can implement it as follows:

```
import threading

thread = threading.Thread(target=regular_ping, args=(ip,))
thread.start()
# Rest of the program
thread.join()
```